# Best way to format a TimeSpan depending on length [ASP.NET Core MVC]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, formatting, timespan

I am working on a .NET Core MVC app that takes a user's run data as input and stores it in a database. The user will input a Time (total time of run), Pace (per mile), and Distance (in miles) and then submit. Both Time and Pace are TimeSpan's.

Here is where my problem comes up:

Example: If I want to enter in 45 mins and 15 seconds for Time, the user has to enter in `00:45:15`, which they aren't going to do. If they were to enter in `45:15`, it would show up in the DB as 45 hours 15 minutes - which is obviously not what we want.

My question is, what would be the best way to format this so that when a user enters in this format `XX:XX` it stores the run as minutes:seconds, but if a user enters in `XX:XX:XX` (for runs over an hour) it stores as hours:minutes:seconds?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about one size fits all

```
        foreach (var s in new[] {"00:45:15", "45:15" })
        {
            var parsed = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(s, new[] { "mm\\:ss", "hh\\:mm\\:ss" }, null, out var result);
            Assert.IsTrue(parsed);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Hours);
            Assert.AreEqual(45, result.Minutes);
            Assert.AreEqual(15, result.Seconds);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem with some string interpolation. Consider the following:

```
<input type="number" name="minutes" min="0" max="59">
<input type="number" name="seconds" min="0" max="59>
```

And then for the C#

```
var minuteTime = Request.Form["minutes"]
var secondTime = Request.Form["seconds"]
FormattableString finalDate = "$00:{minuteTime}:{secondTime}"
//Write to the database with model
```

Comment: how does this address a non-0 hours value?